# HTLM5 / Javascript library to schedule events by resources and dates vertically

Tags: javascript, html, calendar, jquery

**Setting**

We need a (Javascript / HTML5) scheduler to manage (create, edit, delete) client - therapist appointments.

The grid system in the picture shown below is how we have managed the appointments in the past using a popular (offline) grid application :-). We would now like to use an online scheduler that is to be integrated into our intranet web application (Laravel 5).

[image]

**Scheduler requirements**

As the grid shows, we would like to use a vertical alignment of the days and weeks shown in the scheduler. So far, I have not been able to find something similar on the web to use. All schedulers and calenders use a horizontal alignment of days and weeks. We need a vertical alignment because we always need to have a large overview of all appointments. The list of days and weeks should be endless and with some zoom functionality, give a quick overview of what is scheduled per week, month, quarter year, and so on. Further, we need to be able to move an appointment within the list and to also create and delete appointments.

**Question**

So far, we have used the JQuery plug-in fullcalendar to implement the functionality we need. But with the horizontal alignment, we loose a great deal of overview. Also the scheduler add-on of the lib as shown on the site does not provide a vertical alignment. Is it possible to use fullcalender for our purpose? Or maybe there exists a system written in Javascript/ HTML5 that I can use to easily implement this type of scheduler.